# MessageUI for watchOS

Tags: objective-c, messageui, watchos

I am have an app and in the iPhone app, we use MessageUI Framework, but when I try to add it to my Apple Watch Extension InterfaceController.h file like so:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

I get this error:

```
'MessageUI/MessageUI.h' file not found
```

Does watchOS not support MessageUI ? and do I have readd the framework again?

Answer (score 0):

WatchOS 2 does not support many of the standard frameworks found on iOS (including MessageUI). If you wish to do something more intensive that requires the need of frameworks available only on iOS, then you can use watch connectivity.

I asked this question a while ago, about a different framework, but the same idea applies: [How to reference non-supported frameworks in Watch OS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006593/how-to-reference-non-supported-frameworks-in-watch-os-2/33171106#33171106)